# MATLAB: A specific line of a .m file slows down the speed (potential bottleneck?)

Tags: algorithm, performance, matlab, cell-array

I have encountered an unexpected problem, while i am trying to implement an AC-3 algorithm in MATLAB. It's an AI algorithm, to achieve local consistency for networks of binary constraints.

Well, firstly, let me explain this to you. In general, what i am trying to do here, is check whether an "arc" (xi,xj) of variables already exists or not in a FIFO queue called Q. If yes, i do nothing. If it does not already exists, i have to insert the arc into the Q(into the back, FIFO-style) and use break to exit the if statement. I hope that it is pretty much clear until now.

To add this arc (xi,xj) to the Q, i use a replicated matrix Q2, just like Q, which holds all the arcs of type (xi,xj) the whole time, while the initial Q is making some deletions of arcs through the iterations of a for loop, following the theory of the AC-3 algorithm.

There is the code the problem is located:

```
for m=1:length(Q2)
       alreadyExists = any(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, Q2{m}), Q)); 
         if alreadyExists==0;     
            fprintf('\nRe-entering in Q arc(x%d,x%d)...\n',Q2{m}(1),Q2{m}(2));
            Q{end+1}=[Q2{m}];
            re_enteringQ_cntr=re_enteringQ_cntr+1; 
            break;
         end
end
```

So what i am doing in line:

```
 alreadyExists = any(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, Q2{m}), Q));
```

Is just to compare every arc (xi,xj) stored in Q2 with x, a variable returned by another function, which is also another arc.

And here is the problem, using profile viewer on MATLAB:

[image]

It is really weird. About ~70 million calls this specific code in nearly 12 minutes of "real" time?! I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the program, as it seemed it would be executed for a really long time.This cannot be right of course, it is a kind of bottleneck and I can not find any solution until now.

To catch you up guys, in every function and .m file of my whole algorithm i do preallocations for all the matrices, cell arrays and vectors i use, in order to boost up the speed.

Any ideas, any thoughts and/or feedback would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You are using `cellfun` on an anonymous function and cell matrix Q so effectively you are calling the anonymous function many, many times. Can you vectorize that call to cellfun? Do you really need a cell matrix? Maybe bsxfun would be applicable here (and faster)? I can try to help you but you need to tell me how Q and Q2 are structured.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. First of all, it seems that Q and Q2 must certainly be cell arrays. I am not also sure bsxfun would work here, because of the cell arrays. How exactly could I vectorize that call to cellfun? Also, Q and Q2 are like:   >> Q{1}

ans =

     0   127     1    56   .They store double type arrays inside them, which the first two are the variables that are taking part in the binary constraint, the third one is the operator (1 stands for operator >) and the fourth value (56 for example) is a constant value for comparisons.

Comment: So Q always store the same number of values in each cell? If so - you could use matrices - this would be much faster. If you use matrices you could try something like: `len = size(Q, 2); any(sum(bsxfun(@eq, Q, Q2(m, :)), 2) == len);` - this would be equivalent to your cellfun call.

Comment: Get rid of these cell arrays and try to use matrices. As @mmagnuski said, if `Q` and/or `Q2` elements are always the same size, you can (you should really) convert them to matrices before running loops on them. If the elements are not the same size (=> cell array needed), you could consider calculating a sort of `checksum` which yield only one scalar number for every elements of `Q/Q2`. Then instead of scanning the queue for existing elements, just scan the array of checksum for a single value, this should be considerably faster and offset the extra time needed to maintain the checksum array.